# When do BOOL properties get deleted in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

In objective-c, using ARC, when do BOOL (or int) properties get deleted?
For example, suppose I have

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL happy;  //Suppose this is a property of class Face
```

In this case when does the happy property get deleted? I ask this because there is no specifier such as `strong` or `weak`.  In fact, Xcode will not even let you declare this property as `strong` or `weak`?

My guess is that it has something to do with BOOLs being stored on the stack and regular, object properties being stored in the heap, but this is just a guess.

Thanks

Comment: and why would BOOL need to be nonatomic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the `BOOL` is part of your class, it gets deleted when the class gets released by the autorelease pool. Otherwise, any primitives on the stack goes away when the variable goes out of scope. There's no need to memory manage primitive types, unless you explicitly have pointers to them.

Answer (score 0):

BOOL properties get never deleted, properties of Primitives type cannot be retained or release 
Primitives are int, bool, float, double, etc..